# MKMapView unexpected crash issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, mkmapview, mapkit

In viewDidLoad I have only 2 strings:

```
MKMapView *mapViewMy = [[MKMapView alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:mapViewMy];
```

And the app crashed on "[self.view addSubview:mapViewMy]". I use iOS7. It crashes both on devices and simulators. When I use simulator I have crash report:

```
2013-11-06 13:34:15.948 MyBex JAPanel[36286:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0216c5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01eef8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0211ebcc -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 844
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0211e870 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 64
    4   UIKit                               0x01190b67 PushNextClassForSettingIMP + 358
    5   UIKit                               0x0118905e TaggingAppearanceObjectSetterIMP + 43
    6   UIKit                               0x00d6d8de -[UIViewController _setUpLayoutGuideConstraintIfNecessaryAtTop:] + 424
    7   UIKit                               0x00d6c1c3 -[UIViewController topLayoutGuide] + 140
    8   MapKit                              0x023d16a8 -[MKMapView updateLayoutGuides] + 82
    9   MapKit                              0x023d17e7 -[MKMapView didMoveToSuperview] + 68
    10  UIKit                               0x00cba636 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 472
    11  UIKit                               0x00cba388 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 260
    12  UIKit                               0x00cc54c1 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1847
    13  UIKit                               0x00cb89b1 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
    14  UIKit                               0x01189077 TaggingAppearanceObjectSetterIMP + 68
    15  MyBex JAPanel                       0x0001180e -[MapViewController configureView] + 142
    16  MyBex JAPanel                       0x00011778 -[MapViewController viewDidLoad] + 88
    17  UIKit                               0x00d71318 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 696
    18  UIKit                               0x00d96b15 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 39
    19  UIKit                               0x00d9702b -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 235
    20  UIKit                               0x00d97123 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 78
    21  UIKit                               0x00d9809c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 645
    22  UIKit                               0x00d98cb9 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    23  UIKit                               0x00ed2181 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    24  UIKit                               0x00cc8267 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    25  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f0181f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    26  QuartzCore                          0x005c82ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    27  QuartzCore                          0x005bc0d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    28  QuartzCore                          0x005bbf40 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    29  QuartzCore                          0x00523ae6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    30  QuartzCore                          0x00524e71 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    31  QuartzCore                          0x005e1430 +[CATransaction flush] + 52
    32  UIKit                               0x00c79dc9 _afterCACommitHandler + 131
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x021344ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0213441f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x02112344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x02111ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x021118db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    38  GraphicsServices                    0x027f29e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    39  GraphicsServices                    0x027f2809 GSEventRun + 104
    40  UIKit                               0x00c5dd3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    41  MyBex JAPanel                       0x0003bc0d main + 141
    42  libdyld.dylib                       0x03423725 start + 0
    43  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I checked, both `mapViewMy and self.view` are not nil.

Comment: which line does it point to during the crash?

Comment: when there is a simulator is points to [self.view addSubview:mapViewMy]; line

Comment: How do you call `configureView` ?

Comment: in viewDidLoad I use [self configureView];

Comment: What happens if you try to add an empty `UIView` with any random frame ?

Comment: The method causing this crash is `configureView` in `MapViewController` class. Check there, seems like you are adding a `nil` subview on the `MapViewController`'s view.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like in our **viewDidLoad** your object is miss referencing

1. Make sure you have added Framework of **MapKit**
2. Import Map Kit & Delegate in your .h file

Try this code :

```
MKMapView *mapViewMy = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]; 
mapViewMy.delegate=self; 

[self.view addSubview:mapViewMy];
```

You need to add map kit delegates methods. :)

Comment: I've tried the code with delegate at first, but then removed it for test purposes. So  that doesn't help

Comment: Provide your entire code snippet for ViewDidLoad, as is seems your crash report throw error of Array Bound. also let me know your adding map view programatically or by using IB ?

Answer (score 0):

in **.h** file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
//import MKMapkit framwork

@interface mapSampleViewController : UIViewController {
    <MKMapViewDelegate>//mapview delegate
{
        MKMapView *mapView;

}
```

in **.m** file

add this code in **viewdidload**

```
 mapView= [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

 mapView.delegate = self;

 [self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

Comment: Why do you declare `mapView` if you don't use it ? What is the difference with his code ? There's no `Map` var.

Comment: if you are using your map globally declare it in .h file

@PaulGalavic did you declare MkMapViewDelegate like as  <MKMapViewDelegate> in .h file